# Vtk charts break in QT, "no override found for 'vtkContextDevice2D"

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I can't use any type of vtk 2D chart in QT without getting the error:
"Generic Warning: In vtkContextDevice2D.cxx, line 31 Error: no override found for 'vtkContextDevice2D".

There is limited discussion on this with almost all suggestions being to upgrade qt/vtk, but theses are year old and I am on the newest versions.

This doesn't help either:

```
include "vtkAutoInit.h"   
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2); // VTK was built with vtkRenderingOpenGL2  
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

Info: Win64 on 64bit machine, vtk8.2.0, Qt5.13.0, compiled/built in MCVS2017(Release x64) with cmake3.15.0
(Everything else works fine, even 3D renderings with vtk)

Code:

```
view->SetInteractor(this->qvtkWidgetRight->GetInteractor());  
this->qvtkWidgetRight->SetRenderWindow(view->GetRenderWindow());
```

[What the error produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFO1r.png)

Comment: This is strange: I found source code of [`vtkContextDevice2D`](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Context2D/vtkContextDevice2D.h) on github but I couldn't find any `vtkContextDevice2` by google (except in your question). Typo?

Comment: With current source on github: `vtkContextDevice2D.cxx:31: vtkAbstractObjectFactoryNewMacro(vtkContextDevice2D)`

Comment: Sorry, just realized what you meant, it is indeed a typo.

Comment: And I just want to emphasize that I can succesfully do 3D renderings of vtk in qt without error, but anything in 2D breaks like so. Everything in cmake was error free as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I run this example:[QtBarChart](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Qt/QtBarChart/), and I fixed this issue with linking with these [vtk libraries](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Qt/QtBarChart/#cmakeliststxt):

```
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkChartsCore
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkInteractionStyle
  vtkRenderingContext2D
  vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingCore
  vtkRenderingFreeType
  vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingOpenGL2
  vtkViewsContext2D
  QUIET
```

It seems I missed some libraries.

Comment: I completely forgot to update this question with an answer. It turned out that I was missing vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2 in my CMake file.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I was already linking vtkRenderingConextOpenGL2 (statically). I needed the following lines in my main.cpp to fix the problem: ```#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2)
```